# Can't figure out basic Dwarf Fortress dwarf control

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am very confused about this. I know how to start a job, but I can't figure out how to assign a dwarf to it. I've looked around a lot, and can't find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: I remember this part of learning DF, it takes a while to get use to, but, when you do figure it out, it's really helpful cause it eliminates micromanaging on a macro scale. (Plus it adds more fun.)

Comment: Nerd4life123, now wait until you manage to discover how job management works using the manager. That will make stuff a lot easier!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've got it backwards; Dwarves don't pick jobs, jobs pick dwarves. When a job is created, it picks the nearest dwarf with the appropriate labors enabled.

If you've set a job and are finding it's not getting completed, chances are, you don't have enough dwarves with the corresponding labor enabled.

While you can assign labors manually ([Magmawiki link](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Labor#Viewing_labors)), this method usually becomes untenable once you have more than a handful of dwarves.

Therefore, I would suggest you look into [Dwarf Therapist](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Utilities#Dwarf_Therapist), an external program that you can run alongside dwarf fortress which will take care of all labor assignations from one simple screen.

Comment: [DFHack](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=91166.0) also has a similar interface built into the game via the unit screen (`u` - `l`) since version 0.34.11 r2.

Comment: The only people allowed to call the Dwarf Therapist labor assignment screen "simple" operate nuclear power plants or fly passenger jets for a living.

Comment: @Shadur It is as complicated as an simple spreadsheet application. Don't overreact. It just contains a lot of information, as DF has a lot of jobs.